# How to reset Chrome's remembering of long URLs

Tags: google-chrome

As an example, I want to visit **facebook.com**, however at some point, Chrome decided to remember "**facebook.com/something/something/something/something/something**". Now whenever I type "fa" it suggests the latter, requiring me to re-type "facebook.com".

Is there a way to reset these long suggestions without clearing out all my suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> these items.

Scroll down the list with the keyboard or hover your mouse over them, and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> and the item will be forgotten.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]